# jquery manipulate with matches inside replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
.replace(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/g, '<I>$1</I>')
```

Do it's possible to manipulate with $1 ? I mean wrap to sunction function ?

Ex:

```
.replace(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/g, '<I>'+test($1)+'</I>')
```

This example return that `$i` is undefined/

Comment: You don't define `$i` anywhere in your code. Also, why are you matching against two literal `$`, i.e. `\$\$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .match, for example:

```
var matches = str.match(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/g);
if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
  str = str.replace(matches[0], '<I>' + test(matches[0]) + '</I>');
}
```